# Merge two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, search, matrix

I have two matrices. One is of size 1,000,000 x 9 and the other is 500,000 x 9.

The columns have the same meaning and the first 7 columns have the function of a key. Correspondingly, the last two columns have data character. There are many overlapping key values in both of the matrices and I would like to have a big matrix to compare the values. This big matrix should be of dimension 1,000,000 x 11.

For example:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 20; 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 30 40];
B = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 60];
```

A merged matrix would look like this:

```
C = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 20 50 60; 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 30 40 0 0];
```

As you can see, the first row of C has columns 8, 9 from matrix A and columns 10,11 from matrix B. The second row uses the columns 8, 9 from matrix A and 0,0 for the last to columns because there is no corresponding entry in matrix B.

I have accomplished this task theoretically, but it is very, very slow. I use loops a lot. In any other programming language, I would sort both tables, would iterate both of the tables in one big loop keeping two pointers.

**Is there a more efficient algorithm available in Matlab using vectorization or at least a sufficiently efficient one that is idiomatic/short?**

*(Additional note: My largest issue seems to be the search function: Given my matrix, I would like to throw in one column vector 7x1, let's name it `key` to find the corresponding row. Right now, I use bsxfun for that:*

```
targetRow = data( min(bsxfun(@eq, data(:, 1:7), key), [], 2) == 1, :);
```

*I use `min` because the result of bsxfun is a vector with 7 match flags and I obviously want all of them to be true. It seems to me that this could be bottleneck of a Matlab algorithm)*

Comment: Semantically, I would always prefer `all(X,2)` over `min(X,[],2)==1` for a logical array. Not sure if it is any faster though.

Comment: *"This could be a bottleneck"* - you can actually check whether it is! Try using the `profiler` to display which lines / sections of your code are using the most time. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html Namely, `profile on; <yourCodeHere>; profile viewer;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with `ismember` and some indexing:

```
% locates in B the last ocurrence of each key in A. idxA has logicals of
% those keys found, and idxB tells us where in B.
[idxA, idxB] = ismember(A(:,1:7), B(:,1:7),'rows'); 
C = [ A zeros(size(A, 1), 2) ];
C(idxA, 10:11) = B(idxB(idxA), 8:9); % idxB(idxA) are the idxB != 0
```

Comment: This is much more concise than my suggestion. `ismember` is a good shout, does this allow for B being bigger than A though? Maybe a check is required at the start and a variable switch if needed. Commenting your code might help as it is very information-dense.

Comment: It does work with bigger `B`, the only thing is to specify what to do with the duplicate keys. In my case it goes for the last occurrence.

Comment: But `C` is initialised to have the same number of rows as `A`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood from the OP when he says that `A` is 1,000,000 x 9, and the result should be 1,000,000 x 11. Therefore, what this solution does is locating in `B` the last occurrence of each row of `A`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was just learning about the implementation of your answer because I didn't know how it worked at first. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I added some comments. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: this is very concise and quite fast!! I choose this one because of this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, only tested with your simple example.

```
% Initial matrices
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 20;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 30 40];
B = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 60];

% Stack matrices with common key columns, 8&9 or 10&11 for data columns
C = [[A, zeros(size(A,1),2)]; [B(:,1:7), zeros(size(B,1),2), B(:,8:9)]];
% Sort C so that matching key rows will be consecutive
C = sortrows(C,1:7);

% Loop through rows
curRow = 1;
lastRow = size(C,1) - 1;
while curRow < lastRow
    if all(C(curRow,1:7) == C(curRow+1,1:7))
        % If first 7 cols of 2 rows match, take max values (override 0s)
        % It may be safer to initialise the 0 columns to NaNs, as max will
        % choose a numeric value over NaN, and it allows your data to be
        % negative values.
        C(curRow,8:11) = max(C(curRow:curRow+1, 8:11));
        % Remove merged row
        C(curRow+1,:) = [];
        % Decrease size counter for matrix
        lastRow = lastRow - 1;
    else
        % Increase row counter
        curRow = curRow + 1;        
    end
end
```

Answer:

```
C = [0     0     0     0     0     0     0    10    20    50    60
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    30    40     0     0]
```

Comment: yes, this is a nice idea, thank you! I still gave the mark to ibancg because it is shorter. Have an upvote, though